# ubuntu 14.04 "didn't get a playback URI on entry file:///*"

Tags: 14.04, sound, rhythmbox, mp3, codecs

I installed Ubuntu on my Chromebook via Crouton. Everything went great but I got problems with my mp3 playback.

I can't play my mp3 files in Rhythmbox. Rhythmbox says "didn't get a playback URI on entry file:///*

I also can't move my mp3 files to Audacity. Audacity closed it self.

After a bit of googling I installed the Ubuntu restricted extras. But I wont work.

Can someone help me?

greets Dominik

Answer (score 9):

I just ran into the same issue on version 15.04 and after looking around and trying different solutions, I found a fix. Detailed at [Rhythmbox doesn't add/import MP3s from ~/Music on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617816/rhythmbox-doesnt-add-import-mp3s-from-music-on-ubuntu-gnome-15-04)

Basically, if the Rhythmbox database gets corrupted somehow, Rhythmbox "forgets" that it can load and play MP3 files, so the trick is to remove or rename the database, so that Rythmbox creates a new, uncorrupted library.

The choices that were presented on the other page were either to

- Delete the database:

  ```
  rm ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml
  ```
- or rename it:

  ```
  mv ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml.bak
  ```

And then start the import again.