# Rhythmbox doesn't add/import MP3s from ~/Music on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04

Tags: rhythmbox, music, 15.04, mp3, ubuntu-gnome

I just installed ***Ubuntu Gnome 15.04***, all my music is located in `/home/user/Music/`, e.g. `/home/user/Music/Back to The Future`.

I run Rhythmbox and try to import all MP3s to the player, but nothing happens. I selected the path `/home/user/Music/`, but `Import x listed tracks` remains disabled. I checked the preferences, the parameter `Music files are placed in` has the right value: `file:///home/user/Music`. Why can't Rhythmbox just import my MP3s? What should I do in order to see these files inside Rhythmbox library?

All needed codecs are installed already. When I click on MP3-file it's opened with video player and played there. I paid attention that Gnome Music also doesn't display MP3s inside of `~/Music`, probably, there is the same root of these two problems.

Execution of

```
ls -l ~/.local/share/rhythmbox
```

Returns:

```
total 132
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   1386 May  3 22:20 playlists.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user      0 May  3 21:31 podcast-timestamp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 129653 May  3 22:16 rhythmdb.xml
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Based on our discussion, I assume that the database was corrupted.

Delete it:

```
rm ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml
```

or rename it:

```
mv ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml.bak
```

And start the import again.

Comment: Works for me after doing 'sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras' (may not be necessary for everyone). Ubuntu 16.04 running cinammon 3.

Comment: Deleting the database AND installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras` was the fix for me.

Comment: Indeed didn't work for me.  I suspect that this is the restricted formats issue mentioned by msaad, and amusingly this _just_ started happening after an update. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to decode and play MP3 files, You need to install required decoder which is not installed on Ubuntu by default, And are provided in the package called "ubuntu-restricted-extras".

Run this in a terminal to install that package :
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

After installing those, Try to import your MP3 files again.
If failed (Which is your problem now !) it's probably because the database was corrupted.

So as A.B. said, You can just delete the database and re-import :
`rm ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml`

At this stage the shouldn't be any problem with Rhythmbox importing mp3 files.

Answer (score 1):

For me, on 16.04LTS, import suddenly stopped working after an update. The fix was to install the ubuntu-restricted-extras as above, then pause and close rhythmbox, then start rhythmbox again; then, import was working again. I did not delete or rename rhythmdb.xml . This is worth a try before you re-import your entire collection.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem of no music imported or playable which began when Rhythmbox tried to import my music before the mp3 codecs were loaded. Having subsequently loaded the correct codecs, my solution was to close Rhythmbox, then open the Files browser, selecting Show Hidden Files from the View drop down, then clicking through the folders .local, share, rhythmbox,then right-clicking on the rhythmdb.xml database file and selecting rename to rhythmdb.bakxml and then restarting Rhythmbox which immediately began importing all the files from my default music folder. Rhythmbox created a brand new rhythmdb.xml file on its own and now all my mp3 files have been imported to the library and are playable.

Comment: This is essentially the same as [A.B.'s earlier answer](/a/618148/175814).

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04. First installed clementine instead of rythmbox. Worked fine. Later I opened an .ogg soundfile with rythmbox and immedeatly after that, rythmbox started to import all .mp3 files. Now I have both players that work. Maybe it helps for someone.