# Rhythmbox not playing and finding music, Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: rhythmbox

I had a fresh install yesterday, since then Rhythmbox is not playing as well as not finding music from Musics folder.

I have installed Ubuntu-restricted extra, please help

---

I've chosen "File - Add Music" and then selected the Music folder but no music is imported

Comment: create a random folder and copy an audio file to that folder.  Use File-Add Music and navigate to that folder - does the number change from "Import 0 listed tracks" to "Import 1 listed track" ? - you should be able to click that button to import the music file.

Comment: @fossfreedom Yes moving files to other folder (not Music) rhythmbox is able to import. why is that?

Comment: not sure - how about go into the preferences and select the music tab - make sure the "watch my library for new files" is ticked.

Comment: @fossfreedom I already did that. my problem is solved, i moved all my files into temp folder and back to music folder, now rhythmbox is find all the music. weird :-/

Comment: excellent - well done.  Dont forget to post that as an answer and you can accept your own answer as well.

Comment: Same problem here. This helped:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/617816/rhythmbox-doesnt-add-import-mp3s-from-music-on-ubuntu-gnome-15-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may sound weird, but it worked for me.

I moved all of my music files to a temp folder and moved back to Music folder, now Rhythmbox is able to add all files into its library.